# Add tables to custom query in cakephp

Tags: cakephp

Im trying to replicate the following query in cakephp:

```
SELECT *
FROM uploads, proposals
WHERE proposals.id = uploads.proposal_id AND proposals.tender_id = 10
```

Im using the find method in the Upload model with the following conditions:

```
$conditions = array(
  'Proposal.id' => $id,
  'AND' => array(
    'Upload.proposal_id' => 'Proposal.id'
  )
);
return($this->find('list', array('conditions' => $conditions)));
```

but im getting this query instead

```
SELECT `Upload`.`id`, `Upload`.`title` 
FROM `kumalabs_lic`.`uploads` AS `Upload` 
WHERE `Proposal`.`id` = 10 AND `Upload`.`proposal_id` = 'Proposal.id'
```

as you can see, the proposals table is missing, can somebody explain me how can i make this query?

Thanks :)

Comment: How do you define your Upload model? it have relationship declaration to Proposal model?

Comment: Upload belongs to Proposal, here's the code: http://pastie.org/5079273

Comment: after look at your code, I create one answer to resolve your problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the model have association, CakePHP automatically join the table by `'contain'` keyword. Try code bellow:

```
public function getProposalsFromTender($id){
   $data = $this->find('all', array(
      'conditions' => array('Proposal.id' => $id),
      'fields' => array('Upload.*', 'Proposal.*'),
      'contain' => array('Proposal')
  ));
  return($data);
}
```

Note:
CakePHP use explicit join instead of implicit join like `...from proposals, uploads...`

Comment: it worked! just a question, it works with find "all" but not with "list". Any idea why it might be?

Comment: The purpose of "list" is to get one dimension of array. You can specify for 'fields' keyword about one or two which one as array key and other as value. It's also can to define more then two keywords on 'fields' but not recommended IMHO.
If you need to get list of "Proposal", just use $this->Proposal->find('list', ... Look at http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find-list

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you use the linkable behaviour for this. It is much easier than the default way of doing joins in CakePHP. It works with the latest version of CakePHP, as well as 1.3.

[CakePHP Linkable Behavior](https://github.com/rafaelbandeira3/linkable)

You would then modify your find to look like this:

```
return($this->find('list', array(
    'link' => array('Proposal'),
    'conditions' => array(
            'Proposal.id' => $id,
    ),
    'fields' => array(
            'Upload.*',
            'Proposal.*',
    ),
)));
```

CakePHP will automatically join on your primary / foreign key, so no need to have the

```
'Upload.proposal_id' => 'Proposal.id'
```

condition.

Though you don't need that condition, I also want to point out that you are doing your AND wrong. This is how you do AND and OR in CakePHP

```
        'conditions' => array(
                'and' => array(
                    'field1' => 'value1', // Both of these conditions must be true
                    'field2' => 'value2'
                ),
                'or' => array(
                    'field1' => 'value1', // One of these conditions must be true
                    'field2' => 'value2'
                ),
        ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with that JOIN syntax but I believe it equals this:

```
SELECT *
FROM uploads
INNER JOIN proposals ON proposals.id = uploads.proposal_id
WHERE proposals.tender_id = 10
```

... so you need something similar to this:

```
// Untested
$conditions = array(
    'Proposal.id' => $id,
    'joins' => array(
        array(
            'alias' => 'Proposal',
            'table' => 'proposals',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => 'Proposal.id = Upload.proposal_id',
        ),
    ),
);
```

Of course, this is a direct translation of your JOIN. If your models are properly related, it should all happen automatically.